# Prepopulate input fields on another site from url

Tags: javascript, html

I know I can grab the url and get values for input fields on a page if I control that page and can write some javascript on that page, BUT is it possible to load a URL with a query string and force some input fields on someone else's page to use those values?

This would be a page I have no control over, I'm just wondering if it can be done. Can I prepopulate fields on a page in this manner?

Comment: No you can't, but if those inputs are a form that you'd like to submit, you can't set the GET or POST data to do the same thing without filling in the form ?

Comment: No we are not filling out a form, just sending a link in an email. I didn't think it was doable!